# "all the best" - distinction, comma or no comma?

Tags: commas

How can one distinguish between:

A) "We wish you **all the best**!"

and

B) "We wish **you all** the best!" ?

*We wish you all, the best!* - is that correct for version B)?

Comment: Isn't the second one spelt *y'awl*?

Comment: Correct, for version B, would be "We wish, to all of you, the best."  Or some such.

Comment: You simply listen to what is said. What is the question here?

Comment: Words in bold type have no grammatical value, and are only there in order to emphasise something. Thus the two sentences are, in essence, exactly the same.

Comment: @WS2 no, they're not the same: all either means the whole group of individuals present or it means "only everything from the very best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each statement is identical in meaning, needing no punctuation.

It can be offered to one person (A) or more than one person (B):

A: "George! We wish you all the best!"

B: "Dear Programming Group! We wish you all the best!"

You could write B like so: "Dear Programming Group! We wish you all, 'All the best!'" but it is a little awkward-looking and takes away from the flow of the original whilst retaining the meaning.

Comment: But it's two different meanings, all either means the whole group of individuals present or it means it means only everything the best...

Comment: Well if they intend to mean 'the best to all of you', they should either write simply that, or else 'We wish you all, the best'. Bold type is no substitute for proper punctuation. Next we shall be drawing pictures and diagrams to express ourselves!